# Are the pipeline steps followed when Predicting after GridSearch CV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I'm using GridSearchCV in combination with a pipeline that includes standardization as a first step. I've found that when predicting for a test dataset using the .predict method of GridSearchCV, the results differ from when the pipeline steps are implemented manually. I've created a simplified version of my script below, to show that the errors found differ. For the purpose of simplicity, the search space consists of only 1 value per parameter.

I'm aware that the difference here is very small. But in my original code, this difference is significantly larger. Thus I am trying to understand what causes the difference between the two methods

Initializing the data

```
import random

import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVR

random.seed(5)
np.random.seed(5)

x_train = np.random.rand(1000,4)
y_train = np.random.rand(1000,1)

x_test = np.random.rand(100,4)
y_test = np.random.rand(100,1)

C_space = 1
epsilon_space = 0.04
gamma_space = 0.001
```

Implementing a Pipeline

```
cv_folds = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)

steps = [
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
    ('svr', SVR(kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma_space, C=C_space, epsilon=epsilon_space))
    ]
pipe = Pipeline(steps, verbose=0)

search_space = [{
        'svr__gamma':[gamma_space],
        'svr__C':[C_space], 
        'svr__epsilon':[epsilon_space]
        }]

mod = GridSearchCV(pipe, search_space,
    scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=5, verbose=0, return_train_score=True, refit=True)
svr = mod.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = svr.predict(x_test)

error = mean_absolute_error(y_pred, y_test)
```

Implementing the steps manually

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_test)

manual_svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma_space, C=C_space,
    epsilon=epsilon_space).fit(x_train_scaled, y_train)

y_pred_manual = manual_svr.predict(x_test_scaled)

error_manual = mean_absolute_error(y_pred_manual, y_test)
```

The outcome is:

```
Pipeline error is: 0.23495746730222067
Manual error is: 0.23487379770774958
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fitting the `StandardScaler` within `GridSearchCV` to the **training data**, whereas you are **re**-fitting your "manual" `scaler` to the **test data**. With

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_test)
```

you are **overwriting** the `scaler` fit to the training data!
This is **not** the way using a scaler is intended to. Fit the scaler to the **training data** and then use this scaler to standardize your test data.

Let's compare your output with how it should look like. First let's extract the scaler fit in `GridSearchCV` and standardize the test data with it:

```
gscv_sclr = mod.best_estimator_.named_steps['scaler']
gscv_test_scld = gscv_sclr.transform(x_test)
```

As you can see, this is **not equal** your manually standardized test data:

```
np.allclose(gscv_test_scld, x_test_scaled)
# Out: False
```

Now let's fit the "manual" standardizer only **with the training data** and use this standardizer to transform your test data:

```
scaler_new = StandardScaler()
x_train_scaled = scaler_new.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_scaled_new = scaler_new.transform(x_test)

# and compare it to the gridsearchcv scaler:
np.allclose(gscv_test_scld, x_test_scaled_new)
# Out: True
```

Which is **equal**!
Now use this correctly standardized test set to make your predictions:

```
# this refitting is actually not needed. it is simply here for having separate models...
manual_svr_new = SVR(kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma_space, C=C_space,
    epsilon=epsilon_space).fit(x_train_scaled, y_train)

y_pred_manual_new = manual_svr_new.predict(x_test_scaled_new)

error_manual_new = mean_absolute_error(y_pred_manual_new, y_test)

# And test it:
error_manual_new == error
# Out: True
```

And now you've got the result of your pipeline.